# How to show icon with jquery calender control?

Tags: jquery, jquerydatetimepicker

I am using jqueryDateTimePicker, jquery.datetimepicker.full.js, I want to show calender icon with input control, but icon is not showing, any help?

I am using following datetime control
http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/1788/jQuery-plugin-select-date-and-time-DateTimePicker

Comment: welcome to [SO] please share your code so someone can help you with it. Kindly read [ask]. We are not sure what your code looks like to understand why the "icon" is not showing.

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet and also the files you have included, looks like this library also requires images to be added to the sever in a folder called screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Please try this

Keep to add this `CSS and JS`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({value:'1997/08/25 05:03',  autoOpen:false,});

  $('.fa-calendar').on('click', function () {
    if($('.xdsoft_datetimepicker').css("display")=="block"){
      $('.xdsoft_datetimepicker').css("display","none")
    }else{
      $('.xdsoft_datetimepicker').css("display","block")
    }
  });
  
  $('#datetimepicker').on('focus', function () {
    if($('.xdsoft_datetimepicker').css("display")=="block"){
      $('.xdsoft_datetimepicker').css("display","none")
    }else{
      $('.xdsoft_datetimepicker').css("display","block")
    }
  });
  
});
```

```html
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
<script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.htmldrive.net/edit_media/2015/201512/20151207/datetimepicker-master/jquery.datetimepicker.css"/>
<script src="http://www.htmldrive.net/edit_media/2015/201512/20151207/datetimepicker-master/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>

<input type="datetimepicker" value="" id="datetimepicker">
<span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
```

Comment: @user_mat check the answer.

Comment: Are you want like this?